# Should we use max-width 100% to all images in a website?

Tags: css

If I set img {max-width: 100%) to make a default responsive feature to all images in a website. Is it a good practice? Should I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a good practice but only if you implement it properly through inheritance and proper CSS naming to avoid convoluted HTML and CSS.

Having a default max-width:100% for images is a good thing as it set a standard for your website that no images should be larger than the window or the container in which it resides unless specified.
This way, you can give exceptions to specific images that should be allowed a size larger than the window or for different screen sizes using size specific rules.

Comment: You are very welcome. :)

Comment: Unless you have a parent div without a width defined, and then IE8 collapses it, and sets the width to 0 to the image that has the max-width set. Just a minor detail about older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make use of width and max-width. If the width of the image exceeds max-width, it will be constrained to the max value.

For example, consider the below CSS
img { width: 100%; max-width: 512px; }
If the width of the image exceeds more than 512px, then the image width is restriacted to 512px.

Comment: Thanks. I mean: If I set img {max-width: 100%} to all images in a website, will it affect badly to my website?

Comment: 'Cause I heard others say that just use max-width: 100% when I need. But  I think using max-width: 100% to all images won't make any bugs in layout. Dont know if my thought is right. Really!

Comment: This is not a good idea generally - especially when you have dynamic images that you don't know the dimensions (cms, or user uploaded images, etc).